# Can the string format for date pattern for Pattern Layout in Log4j2 be uppercase?

Tags: java, xml, log4j, log4j2

I am unable to figure out how to uppercase the string format for date pattern in Pattern Layout for `log4j2`.

I have tried to use the replace/regex pattern under Pattern Layout before realizing that it will only return a string as the substitution.

I am currently using the log4j2 XML configuration file.

`%d{dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0} GMT` in the Properties on log4j2 XML configuration file will return 29-Aug-2019 19:48:34 GMT

`replace{%d{dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0}}{[a-z]}{\u} GMT` will return `29-Auu-2019 19:48:34 GMT`

I would like the output to be **29-AUG-2019 19:48:34 GMT** instead of `29-Aug-2019 19:48:34 GMT`.

Comment: *FYI:* Year must be `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Comment: Try : `%replace{%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0}}{[a-z]}{\u$0} GMT`

Comment: @SMaZ - it returned as `30-Auuug-2019 13:30:26 GMT`

Comment: @SMaz - it returned as `30-A\uu\ug-2019 14:07:35`. According to [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html), the third parameter would have to be in its string variable.

Comment: @SMaZ - based on your recent comment/suggestion `%replace{%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}{GMT+0}}{[a-z]}{\\u$0} GMT`

Comment: Correct, After adding comment i realized that its plain `string` not `regex`. This is good question. will try more and add comment if figure out.